Using wall baseboard for baby gates
I installed baby gates thinking I shouldnt mess with the base boards and now realized the height is too much (baby can just slip through the bottom).
Is it possible to attempt to just keep the wooden piece where it is in my picture and only drill the bottom part of the gate directly into the baseboard? Any risks with drilling into the baseboard?


there is always a risk ... someone may have ran wires where you intend to drill ... you didn't worry about the other holes, why are you worrying about this one?

Ive just never drilled into that area before, and I wasn't sure if it made sense to do that vs something else simpler which I havent thought of

"baby can just slip through the bottom" — Be aware that babies have relatively large heads, so check that the body won't squeeze through, not only the head.  Modern cribs etc. have much narrower spacing than traditional versions because babies can push their bodies through leaving their head stuck behind, which is far worse than completely falling through.

Well, the easy button here is to get another piece of wood, screw it to the one already on the wall, but extend it down to the floor.  You may or may not need to use some spacers to clear the baseboard—photo isn't clear about the baseboard profile.  Then fasten the baby gate (lowered down) to the new piece of wood.  No holes in the baseboard, no additional holes in the wall.

thank you! I think ill just do the holes in the baseboard for now since Im unsure how to properly attach to the wood on top and keep it safe.

Well, you already have the wood attached to the wall, right?  Attaching another piece of wood to that existing piece is exactly the same.

I have mounted baby gates directly into baseboards and that works just fine. The only catch is patching. If you are concerned about eventually patching the holes from the screws and painting, the baseboard may be slightly harder to patch properly than the drywall.
